# What is this frame style called?

Tags: frames

[image]

I.e. the inner edges of the frame are "deeper" and closer to the image, whereas the outer edges are closer to the viewer?

Answer (score 2):

It's called a beveled frame...

Comment: ... with a mat, it would appear...

Comment: @twalberg or mount in UK English.

Comment: Why even bother with a matte/mount that thin? Most galleries that require mattes expect at least 2" on each side for smaller prints and even more for larger prints.

Comment: @MichaelC Because it looks good?

Comment: @jarnbjo I think it distracts from the picture. I think it would look better with a darker neutral color and width at least equal to the width of the frame.